# Problem with a fixed column RPGLE program

Tags: rpgle, rpg

I'm having trouble with program maintenance on an older program that I don't fully understand. The program in question is building a file with a generated name to send to a remote FTP server. The problem is that the remote FTP server doesn't get the file. I have figured out that the FTP server is rejecting the password because the login information being sent is inserting the generated file name into the password for the server within the script. This happens on the first line of the script.

```
username P221170632.txtassword
```

I think I have it narrowed down to the following program but because it is in fixed code I am having trouble deciphering it. I'm pretty sure the issue is within the sub routine but there is enough there that I don't understand to keep me from solving it. Here is the code for anyone that can help me figure this out. Thank you very much!

```
      /TITLE WG0503LE - CREATE FTP SCRIPT FOR Unilever Go Puff Flat File
  
  *
 FIN        IP   F   92        DISK
 FOUT       O  A F   92        DISK
 D LN1             S              1    DIM(92)
 D LN2             S              1    DIM(92)
 D snamf           S             18
 D ALPH            C                   CONST('abcdefghijklmnopqrst-
 D                                     uvwxyz')
 IIN        AA  01
 I                                  1   92  LN1
 C     *ENTRY        PLIST
 C                   PARM                    snamf
  *
 C                   Z-ADD     1             X                 3 0
 C                   Z-ADD     1             W                 3 0
 C                   Z-ADD     1             Y                 3 0
 C                   Z-ADD     1             Z                 3 0
  *
 C     *IN61         DOUEQ     *OFF
 C                   EXSR      LOAD
 C                   END
 C                   EXCEPT    OUTLN
  *=============================================
 C     LOAD          BEGSR
  *=============================================
  *   LOAD OUTPUT LINE - EXCHANGE VARIABLES
 C                   MOVEA     LN1(X)        LN2(Y)
 C     '&'           LOOKUP    LN1(X)                                 61
 C     *IN61         IFEQ      *ON
 C     '&'           LOOKUP    LN2(Y)                                 62
 C                   MOVEA     *BLANK        LN2(Y)
 C                   MOVEA     LN1           LINE             92
 C                   ADD       1             X
 C     ALPH          CHECK     LINE:X        W                        65
 C     W             SUB       X             V                 3 0
 C                   ADD       1             V
  **C     V             SUBST(P)  LINE:X        VAR               6
  *
 C                   MOVEA     snamf         LN2(Y)

 C                   MOVEA     LN2           LINE             92
 C     ' '           CHECKR    LINE          Y                        61
 C                   ADD       1             Y
 C                   Z-ADD     W             X
 C                   ENDIF
 C                   ENDSR
  *
 OOUT       EADD         OUTLN
 O                       LN2            B    92
```

Comment: I'd suggest pitching this garbage and re-writing with something like the open source [FTPAPI](https://www.scottklement.com/ftpapi/).

Comment: I would step through the program in debug to check the result of each statement before and after the statement. Hopefully that will help you to understand what the subroutine is doing. In general, the variable in the Result column is what gets changed by the statement. With the LOOKUP opcode, it is the index in the Factor 2 column. For LOOKUP LN1(X), it is X that gets updated. (Strange, but true.)

Comment: OK thank you very much Charles and Barbara! I'll look at the FTPAPI and also step through the program and see what I can figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Having written code in basically every flavor of RPG over forty years (RPG II to free format RPG), I thought I would give a stab at explaining this program's functionality.

At a high level, it appears this program reads an input file that has a template of text lines for setting up an FTP script whereby, placeholder values are replaced with the values sent in via the input parameter (snamf).

First off, in the file specifications (the "F specs") there is a primary input file called "IN" that is being read sequentially until all of the records have been read (you might have heard of the term, the RPG cycle).  And according to the input specification line (the "I spec"), there is only one input field in this file known as "LN1".  Field "LN1" is also defined as a character array ninety-two characters long as well since it is subsequently parsed to determine how output text will be built.  Along with the alternate definition of field "LN1" in the data specification block (the "D specs"), other fields such as the input parameter and other work fields are also defined.

Then in the calculation statements, the RPG cycle basically loops through the lines of code from "C     *ENTRY     PLIST" statement through the "C         EXCEPT   OUTLN" statement for each file record read from file "IN" until all records have been read.

What is happening in the subroutine knowns as "LOAD" is basically as follows:

- The text data in field "LN1" is copied to field "LN2", which will be used as output, to set the initial text information.
- The data in field "LN1" is parsed via calling the "LOOKUP" opcode to locate the position of the ampersand character - evidently the trigger character to note that a substitution will occur.
- If no ampersand was found in the parsing, field "LN2" will be left as is and will be outputted to file OUT as is - indicator "61" will be set off indicating that no more calling of this subroutine will be necessary for this text line.
- If an ampersand was found, the ampersand is changed to a blank in the "LN2" field.
- The lines of code starting with the "CHECK" opcode appear to have been in place to validate that proper alphabetical characters were found, but that appears to be not performing any needed function anymore.
- After the location of the ampersand (which was changed to a blank) is set, the input parameter value, "snamf", is appended to the value in "LN2".
- The subsequent "CHECKR" basically is making sure the field "LN2" is not blank, which sets on indicator "61" forcing another call of this subroutine from the main block of code and checking for any other substitutions.
- After the value of field "LN2" has been updated in the subroutine, it is written out to file "OUT" via the "EXCEPT" opcode.
- The next file record, if any, is read from the input file and the text check and substitution is repeated.

That's about as much as I can take this bit of code from abstract to actual, but hopefully, you have a better understanding of what is going on in the code.